# Getting array name from plist as tableview labels in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, plist

This is my plist file

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Complete</key>
<dict>  
    <key>Autonomic Nervous System</key>
    <array>
        <string>Cholinergic</string>
        <string>Anticholinergic</string>
    </array>
    <key>Peripheral Nervous System</key>
    <array>
        <string>Central relaxants </string>
        <string>Peripheral relaxants </string>
    </array>
</dict>
<key>Chap</key>
<array>
    <string>Autonomic Nervous System</string>
    <string>Peripheral Nervous System</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I am able to get chapter names only when I store it as string under a different key "chap".

Here is the code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "xml", ofType: "plist")
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
    chapters = dict!.object(forKey: "Chap") as! [String]
    ansTopics = dict!.object(forKey: "Complete") as! Array<String>

}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ansTopics.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mainPage", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = ansTopics[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

How do I get the array names as strings and pass it on to tableview elements?  Also, how do I index the topics (stored as strings) for the corresponding chapters for the second table view?

Currently, the `ansTopics` returns a signal `SIGABERT` error.

Comment: Well, what's the error?

Comment: @Alexander Thread1: Sigabert at ansTopics--- the string names are not getting passed - i get an empty screen on simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your key `Complete` contains `Dictionary` not the Array of String. So `ansTopics` should be declare as `[String: Any]`.

```
ansTopics = dict!.object(forKey: "Complete") as! [String: Any] //or Dictionary<String, Any>
```

It is batter if you use `if let` or `guard` to get value from Dictionary instead of force wrapping it.

```
if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!), let arrays = dict.object(forKey: "Complete") as? [String: Any] {
    ansTopics = arrays
}
```

**Edit:** You need to declare one instance property of type array of string name `chapter` and initialized it with `keys` of dictionary and later use that array with your tableview.

```
var ansTopics = [String:Any]()
var chapters = [String]()
```

Now initialized chapters like this way.

```
if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!), let arrays = dict.object(forKey: "Complete") as? [String: Any] {
    self.ansTopics = arrays
    self.chapters = self.ansTopics.keys.sorted()
}
```

Comment: Now I get an error "cannot assign value of type [[String: Any]] to type "[String]"

Comment: Yes thanks..  that works.. But i get the above error in cell.textlabel line ... Any suggestions on how to handle it ?

Comment: @Nish I have misunderstood response complete key contains dictionary not array of dictionary please check the edited answer, After that for your cell's label issue it is happening because your have dictionary, not string, if you look at your info.plist response your Complete key contains Dictionary, so you need to create tableView with multiple section and pass the dictionary key in section title and its value that is array pass it as a row for that section.

Comment: Yeah I think I can do multiple sections....But I was looking at Dictionary key(chapter name) as first page --- arrays as second page --- for some dictionary keys; the array list is more than 10... The above code is a sample.. I have around 11 dictionary key for the app ... And also need to add a third level Table view also... That is the reason I am trying to get the solution for getting the key values as string in the first table view... Should i need to do it manually ? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you are not getting my point; please have a look at "classify" app in playstore... I am developing an exact replica of that app... The link is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.first.medical.medical

Comment: @Nish For first screen if you want to show that chapter you can get all that chapter using `ansTopics.keys` this will give you array of string use that with tableview to display chapter.

Comment: How do i call ansTopics.keys ?

Comment: @Nish like this `let chapters = ansTopics.keys`. Now use chapters array with your tableview methods.

Comment: Okay done that ... But let chapters = ansTopics.keys throws error ? where exactly should i declare it ?

Comment: Initialization of Immutable value chapter is never used consider replacing with '_' or removing it

Comment: @Nish it's simply warning not error, I'm saying is, where you have declare ansTopics, declare one array of string with name `chapters` and then initialize it like `self.chapters = ansTopics.keys` and now use that array with your tableView methods.

Comment: cannot assign value of LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<String<Any String> to String

Comment: @Nish Check my edited answer that will give you idea what to do.

Comment: The code is running ... But the table view is empty in the simulator...

Comment: @Nish You need to post now a second question on SO with your code, this question already solved your issue.

Comment: Yeah.. Its a new problem... Done posting a new one